# Views used in web part show differently than view in list

Tags: 2010, sharepoint-enterprise, web-part, view

I have a list created that shows items grouped by a main level and sub levels below it.  It is a basic list view created using OOB SharePoint functionality, and looks like this when viewing it on the list itself:

[image]

But, when adding the list using this view as a web part on a page, it appears like this below:

[image]

Note the difference in where the totals appear.  Why does this difference occur and how can I fix this?

Comment: Can you please elaborate the steps of adding the view in the Web Part page you are following, because I have added the list view webpart in the page in SP2013 and SP2010, I did not get the issue.

Comment: It seems the XSLT we changed for our CQWP's was the issue. It over-rides the default OOB behaviour, and adding both the custom CQWP and a list web part to the page was the cause of the issue.

Answer (score 0):

Both should be exactly the same.

Do you have a custom masterpage activated? If so, could you try using an Out of the box masterpage?

Comment: It seems the XSLT we changed for our CQWP's was the issue.  It over-rides the default OOB behaviour, and adding both the custom CQWP and a list web part to the page was the cause of the issue.